# Proof that the sum of degree of vertex and it's complement is $(n-1)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let there be a graph $G$ and it's complement $G'$ , if the degree of a vertex in $G$ is added with degree of the corresponding vertex of $G'$ , the sum will be $(n-1)$; where $n$ is the number of vertices. How to prove this ?

Comment: It's a direct corollary from the definition of complement graph.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The union of $G$ and $\overline G$ contains an edge between each pair of the $n$ vertices. Hence, the union is $K_n$ which is the [complete graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) of $n$ vertices.

What is the degree of each vertex of $K_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Given a vertex $u$, there are three types of vertices:

- the vertices which are adjacent to $u$,
- the vertices which are **not** adjacent to $u$ (excluding $u$ itself), and
- $u$.

I depict this below:

[image]

Every vertex has exactly one of these forms, and there are $n$ vertices in total.  Thus, if $u$ is adjacent to $k$ vertices, then it is not adjacent to $n-1-k$ vertices (excluding $u$ itself).  Thus, in the complement graph, $u$ is adjacent to $n-1-k$ vertices.

Thus, if we sum the degree of $u$ in the original graph and in the complement graph, we get $k+(n-1-k)=n-1$.